# Detect css change to element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Is there a way to detect CSS changes to an element via JavaScript?

I've tried WebKitMutationObserver, and though it's close to what I need, it does not fullfil my goal.

Here's what's happening.

1. I load a page with a certain styling
2. I change the "theme" of the page
3. The theming "engine" appends a new stylesheet to the head of the document - this stylesheet would have a series of style overloads. To keep it simple, let's say there's a rule in there that says "change the background color of box 'a' to 'red'".

Now, since I'm not changing the element's style via the "class" or "style" attributes, the event "attributes: true" for the observer never gets fired.

What I need is a way to detect that the color of the element's background has changed to red and then perform some function. Must work in **Webkit**.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not do the related action just after you have appended a new stylesheet?

Comment: Chekout lazyload https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/blob/master/lazyload.js the code will show you how, or just use the library as it can load JS/CSS for you and execute callbacks and take care of all cross-browser issues

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - I can't do as you suggest because there's no guarantee that the browser has rendered the rules by the time I execute my "callback" code. I've already tried this.

Comment: @gillesc - This would likely require a modification to the theming engine. I want to avoid this. I'll take a look at the lazy loader option and see if I can make it work, but a solution not involving changes to the theming engine is preferred.

Comment: That's why I said look at the code first :) That library take care of watching the CSS changes, the code is small, just browse and grab what you need. It will save you headache porting this cross browser (and you will see that depending on the browser the way the CSS is included matters in the detection of it being applied, link tags don't work for all)

Comment: @EricDagenais: you can force the browser to do the reflow immediately, e.g. run `document.width` or something similar. In general, if you are trying to read CSS/layout-related DOM properties, WebKit will surely do the style update/reflow (if one is scheduled) before returning their values to you.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - although appending my stylesheet seems to be causing a reflow itself, even forcing it with "document.body.offsetWidth = document.body.offsetWidth" isn't working :\. For some reason, there still seems to be a lag between the element's CSS change and the code that's executed against it. If however I create an artificial lag of 1s using a timer, then everything works as it should. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you give a reduced test case on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @EricDagenais did you ever solve this? I'm in need of something very similar, but can't figure it out…

Comment: @Luke: yeah - I went with gillesc suggestion of lazyloading my stylesheets. It's not perfect, but works enough for what I need.